# Include Javascript files in NodeJS like PHP

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

In PHP you can include a file and it copies over all **functions** and **variables**.

I'm aware of the require command and the module.export concept for including, but it seems to only allow you to include functions?

I have some code that looks like this.  This code currently works.

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
//console.dir(argv);

//Change connection settings based on stage variable.  Assume localhost by default.
var dbname = argv['stage'] ? argv['stage']+"_db"                              : 'localdb';
var dbuser = argv['stage'] ? process.env.RDS_USERNAME                         : 'admin';
var dbpass = argv['stage'] ? process.env.RDS_PASSWORD                         : 'local123';
var dbhost = argv['stage'] ? "database-"+argv['stage']+".whatever.com"  : 'localhost';

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var connection = new Sequelize(dbname,dbuser,dbpass, {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  operatorsAliases: false, //This gets rid of a sequelize deprecated warning , refer https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8417
  host: dbhost
});

//Import all the known models for the project.
const Users = connection.import(__dirname + "/models/users.js");

connection.sync().then(function() {
  process.exit();//close the nodeJS Script
});
```

**I am trying to put the database connection code into a separate file** but when I do this and try to return the value of the connection for the require, connection never seems to import correctly and I get an error that the import function is not found on connection?

**How would I do this for this example?** If Include worked like PHP I would just include the file and the connection variable would just work.  I'm still new to NodeJS so not sure on the syntax.  I looked around at other answers but I don't understand how it works yet.

My attempt to figure this out looks like this.

```
    module.exports = function(){
    var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
    //console.dir(argv);

    //Change connection settings based on stage variable.  Assume localhost by default.
    var dbname = argv['stage'] ? argv['stage']+"_db"                              : 'localdb';
    var dbuser = argv['stage'] ? process.env.RDS_USERNAME                         : 'admin';
    var dbpass = argv['stage'] ? process.env.RDS_PASSWORD                         : 'local123';
    var dbhost = argv['stage'] ? "database-"+argv['stage']+".whatever.com"  : 'localhost';

    var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    var connection = new Sequelize(dbname,dbuser,dbpass, {
      dialect: 'mysql',
      operatorsAliases: false, //This gets rid of a sequelize deprecated warning , refer https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8417
      host: dbhost
    });
    return connection;

}
```

Then I would say something like `connection = require(./config.js);` and the error would occur at this line, `const Users = connection.import(__dirname + "/models/users.js");` since it can not find the import function anymore.

Comment: You can include whatever a module exposes. This can be a function, but also an object, a promise, a primitive...

Comment: Remove the `module.exports = function ...` wrapper and just do `module.exports = connection` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: I will give that a try

Comment: That worked, thanks! Didn't think about doing it that way.  Put that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revised my answer a bit using PitaJ's suggestion in the comment, here is my revised module file.

```
exports.getSequelizeConnection = function(stage){
      var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2)); //If this file is being used in a script, this will attempt to get information from the argument stage passed if it exists
      var connection;

      //Change connection settings based on stage variable.  Assume localhost by default.
      var dbname = argv['stage'] ? argv['stage']+"_db"                              : 'localdb';
      var dbuser = argv['stage'] ? process.env.RDS_USERNAME                         : 'admin';
      var dbpass = argv['stage'] ? process.env.RDS_PASSWORD                         : 'local123';
      var dbhost = argv['stage'] ? "database-"+argv['stage']+".whatever.com"  : 'localhost';

      //If state variable used during require overide any arguments passed.
      if(stage){
        dbname = stage+"_db";
        dbuser = process.env.RDS_USERNAME
        dbpass = process.env.RDS_PASSWORD
        dbhost = "database-"+stage+".poolservice123.com"
      }

      var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
      var connection = new Sequelize(dbname,dbuser,dbpass, {
        dialect: 'mysql',
        operatorsAliases: false, //This gets rid of a sequelize deprecated warning , refer https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8417
        host: dbhost
      });
      return connection;
    }
```

I then can simply call it like this in my other file...

```
var config = require('./sequelize-config.js');
connection = config.getSequelizeConnection();

//Import all the known models for the project.
const Users   = connection.import(__dirname + "/models/Users.js");
const Events  = connection.import(__dirname + "/models/Calls.js");

//Alter table as needed but do NOT force the change.  If an error occurs we will fix manually.
connection.sync({ alter: true, force: false }).then(function() {
  process.exit();//close the nodeJS Script
});
```

The advantage of this approach is I can use the same config file now for command line scripts and for non-command-line scripts that use the database.